# Weights cannot be saved in the backup folder. [Yolo, Darknet]

Tags: python, yolo, darknet

I am making a Custom YOLOV3 Object Detector in the Google Colab.

When I ran this code below, weights were supposed to be saved in the backup folder in my google drive. However, there were no files with weights.

```
!./darknet detector train data/obj.data cfg/yolov3_custom.cfg darknet53.conv.74
```

To fix this problem, I changed some codes in darknet/scr/detector.c. , but it didn't work.

```
if(i%10000==0 || (i < 1000 && i%100 == 0)){ 
if(i%100==0 || (i < 1000 && i%100 == 0)){
```

Are there any possible solutions to properly save weights?

I also don't know how get rid of this "warning" to show graph in the cola. Is this because of Mac? How can I eliminate this warning.

[image: a running result]

I used this source to create my custom detector.
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Mh2HP_Mfxoao6qNFbhfV3u28tG8jAVGk#scrollTo=wQaH53afmrZC

Answer (score 0):

The warning is showing up bcs google colab or AWS do not have a GUI to display the graphs on, so you need to cancel displaying the curves.

At the end of your command `!./darknet detector train file.data.... file.weights` add this flag `-dont_show` and it will remove the warning.

Answer (score 0):

Use this: `!./darknet detector train data/obj.data cfg/yolov3_custom.cfg darknet53.conv.74 -dont_show -map`